# How do I Lazy Load Gatsby-Plugin-Image with Swiper?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, swiper.js, gatsby-image

Currently when I load my slider from swiper.js gatsby image automatically loads all of the images even though they are not visible to the end user.  This is not the behavior I want.  I want to only load the images for the slide visible or thumbnail slides visible. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It should be managed automatically since Gatsby adds the lazy loading by default.

- In [`gatsby-image` (v2)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/): the `loading` property controls this behavior.

  > Set the browser’s native lazy loading attribute. One of lazy, eager or
  > auto. Defaults to lazy.
- In [`gatsby-image-plugin` (v3)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/): the same `loading` property controls this behavior:

  > Loading behavior for the image. You should set this to "eager" for
  > above-the-fold images to ensure they start loading before React
  > hydration. Defaults to lazy.

In Swiper, in addition, you have a [bunch of properties](https://swiperjs.com/react#swiper-props) that you can lift to the `Swiper` component, in your case, `lazy` is what you are looking for:

```
  let params = {
    // other props
    lazy: true,
  };
```

Then just use it like:

```
  <Swiper {...params}>
   // your slides here
  </Swiper>
```

Comment: It turns out that it's depends on which parameters are selected in the swiper config.

Comment: A combination of both. I'm glad it fixed the issue